# Get data from 2 tables connected using a pivot table (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to get data from 2 tables connected using a pivot table ? for example, in my case I have users table connected to journal table using a pivot table (penulis table). Now I want to get journals data that belonged to specific user. I tried this :

```
$journal_list = DB::table('journal')->where('id_user', '=','id_journal')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

That code above doesn't work. Below are my migrations :

Users table :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('userslug');
            $table->string('nameslug');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->enum('level', ['admin', 'author']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Journal table :

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create('journal', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title', 255);
            $table->text('abstract');
            $table->text('file');
            $table->integer('id_edition')->unsigned();
            $table->string('journalslug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Penulis table (the pivot table)

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('penulis', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // Create tabel penulis
            $table->integer('id_user')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('id_journal')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->timestamps();

            // Set PK
            $table->primary(['id_user', 'id_journal']);

            // Set FK penulis --- user
            $table->foreign('id_user')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');

            // Set FK penulis --- journal
            $table->foreign('id_journal')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('journal')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

View composer :

```
public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('user/show', function ($view) {
            $journal_list = User::where('id', $user_id)->with('journal')->first();
            $view->with('journal_list', $journal_list);
        });
    }
```

Comment: You've copied the code from my answer (to `View Composer` part), but you never said is it work for you or not. So, does it solve the problem? If not, do you get any errors?

Comment: gave me error "undefined variable userID". I don't want to use eloquent, and I wanted to pass the data through view composer. I've updated the question with the view composer @Alexey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Eloquent, you should setup [`belongsToMany()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relation first:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function journals()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Journal');
    }
```

Then use eager loading to load the data:

```
User::where('id', $userId)->with('journals')->first();
```

If you don't want to use Eloquent and just need journals:

```
$journal_ids = DB::table('penulis')->where('id_user', $userId)->get(['id_journal'])->toArray();
$journal_list = DB::table('journal')->whereIn('id', $journal_ids)->paginate(20);
```

Or do the same by using `join()`.

Comment: Tried this, gave me error "undefined variable userID". I don't want to use eloquent, and I wanted to pass the data through view composer. I've updated the question with the view composer

Comment: @AriandoMiller, to pass the data, you need to get the data first. If you get `undefined variable userID` error message, just set it as `$userId = 5` or something like `$userId = auth()->user()->id` if you want to get current user ID. If you don't want to use Eloquent, try non-Eloquent code from my answer.

Comment: I tried both and still it doesn't show journals data the belonged to the specific user. Maybe I messed up with the user id ? I don't want to get the current user id, but selected user id, example, If I click Jon Doe's profile it will show the Jon Doe's contact person data along with the journals that belongs to him

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of the [`Eloquent`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) if you are using `Laravel`

First define the [`relations`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) in your models

```
class User extends Model {

    public function journal(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Journal', 'penulis', 'id_user', 'id_journal');
    }

}


class Journal extends Model {

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'penulis', 'id_journal', 'id_user');
    }

}
```

Of course you need to define the `table` and `fillables` in your model with `table name` and `table columns` respectively.

And to get the specific data related to `users` you can use eloquent,

```
User::with('journal')->paginate(20);
```

This will load 20 `users(paginated)` with related `journal` data.

To know further about the eloquent relationships, take a look at this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships).

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: are you sure you have related data in your pivot table? Cause if you have then it surely should show up